# Url validation based on input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to forcefully add https to all links regardless of whether the link is domain.com http://example.com, https://example.com with or without www.

Also, the text of the links should be of the form example.com or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (eliminating https:// or http://)

```js
    $('#website-url').keyup(function() {
      $('.website_url').html(this.value);
      $('.website_url').prop('href', this.value);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="website-url" class="small mb-0">Website URL ✱</label>
<br>
<input class="form-control text-dark form-control-sm px-1 border-bottom border-success border-1 m-0 mb-2" type="url" id="website-url" placeholder="websiteurl.com" aria-label="Website URL" requiered>
<br>
Welcome to our website: <a href="#" class="website_url">[WEBSITE URL]</a>.
<br>
Please do not continue to use <a href="#" class="website_url">[WEBSITE URL]</a> if you do not agree with all of the terms and conditions stated on this page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make up some variables to work with.
In this example I'm saving the original thing from the input
field in the variable `original_url`.

Then I can make to variations: `stripped_url` is the original
url without https:// or http://

`full_url` is the stripped url with https:// added to the front (again).

```js
$('#website-url').keyup(function() {
  let original_url = this.value;
  let stripped_url = original_url.replace(/https?:\/\//i, '');
  let full_url = "https://" + stripped_url;
  $('.website_url').html(stripped_url);
  $('.website_url').prop('href', full_url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="website-url" class="small mb-0">Website URL ✱</label>
<br>
<input class="form-control text-dark form-control-sm px-1 border-bottom border-success border-1 m-0 mb-2" type="url" id="website-url" placeholder="websiteurl.com" aria-label="Website URL" requiered>
<br>
Welcome to our website: <a href="#" class="website_url">[WEBSITE URL]</a>.
<br>
Please do not continue to use <a href="#" class="website_url">[WEBSITE URL]</a> if you do not agree with all of the terms and conditions stated on this page.
```

Comment: I would add the `i` modifier to your `/https?:\/\//` regexp so it becomes `/https?:\/\//i`, making it case-insensitive, to match `HTTP` (e.g.).